# How do I politely relay to my manager to be a bit more proffesional

Tags: professionalism, manager

little background: Started new job last year my manager been with the company about 40 years, she is 60+.  I am female 40+.  Examples below

1. calls everyone under her "honey".
2. yells from her office "Such-and-such come over here right now!"
3. berates people in front of everybody. not really berates but yells and bangs her hand on the table - we (my coworkers) sit in an open space
4. gossips constantly
5. I'd like her to stop "protecting" me: "VPs and such think you are not doing anything but I protected you, I always protect my people"
6. she takes everything personally: I suggested we reach out to other departments for help to finish project within deadline, she turned it into "Why are you going against me"

in the beginning it was annoying now I am very unhappy. I am not afraid of her or losing my job. It would look bad on my resume if I left now. I think the company is a good fit for me, and the project is really interesting but right now I don't even want to go to work.

Comment: I can't change her... the only person I can change is myself. I am trying to figure out how to approach this situation. Ask her politely not to call me honey? ask her to lower her voice? Walk out of one on one when she gossips? Talk to HR?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere recruiter has my resume, I talk to him once a week but I am reluctant to just leave without trying to find a solution.  the project I was hired to do would be a great addition to my experience plus about 30% jump in the salary.  Maybe the following is relevant: the company is going though heavy restructuring, last month many "old timers" were offered some sort of severance package my manager declined.   She is holding the fort ... I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. calls everyone under her "honey".

This is extremely minor.  She has around 20 years on you and is at the "senior citizen"/elder level in society.

> 2. yells from her office "Such-and-such come over here right now!"

This is somewhat minor.  Yeah, I get that this is annoying, but many working people deal with a lot worse.

> 3. berates people in front of everybody. not really berates but yells and bangs her hand on the table - we (my coworkers) sit in an open space

This is somewhat major.  I don't know anybody that likes being yelled at by their boss in front of everyone.  It would seem this has been her style for a number of years, so I don't see a way you can change this.  Just put it on your list of "cons" of the job.

> 4. gossips constantly

Minor.

> 5. I'd like her to stop "protecting" me: "VPs and such think you are not doing anything but I protected you, I always protect my people"

Given that she's been at your company for 40 years, she must be pretty good at her job and/or keeping it.  She may even be very good at protecting her "people".  I would suggest you learn to appreciate this.  If she is as abrasive as you are depicting, there may be people out to get her, and you may need her protection, like it or not.

> 6. she takes everything personally: I suggested we reach out to other departments for help to finish project within deadline, she turned it into "Why are you going against me"

There are probably things here you aren't aware of, as a new employee.  Reaching out to her perceived competitors/enemies is not a great suggestion to make.  Maybe she's paranoid, or maybe they really are all out to get her.  Who knows.  You might as well give her benefit of the doubt for now.  I'm not saying this is the case, but for all you know, your entire department is constantly under threat of being absorbed into the departments of the people you want to ask for help from.  There are many plausible scenarios for her behavior.  As you said, she has been there for 40 years.  Maybe she knows something you don't.

My opinion is that there really is only one negative from what you said.  Yes, it is a big one, and only you can make the call, but from what you said, you really like the company and your work -- realize that's something not many people have.

Comment: your analysis is spot on. I am aware of a lot of things, simply because the project I am on requires me to talk to other departments. People I reached out for help accepted severance and were no longer competitors. The company started to change last year, long before I arrived.  Our little department (6 people) is on a chopping block, it will be gone before year end. The only way we can survive is by building relationships, breaking silos, and creating solutions.  I just need to figure out positive way of relaying this to my manager.   well new skill to learn - negotiator.